# GetFeedSubmissionResult is not Giving data in response

Tags: amazon-mws

I have tried to call GetFeedSubmissionResult api of Amazon MWS Feed submission. i have one Feedsubmissionid which is successfully gives response in "Amazon MWS Scratchpad" 
but
In this when i am passing the feedsubmissionid into this api it gives below response,

```
Service Response=============================================================================
    GetFeedSubmissionResultResponse
        GetFeedSubmissionResult                ContentMd5                YQtHphFPLIcA4vEOn2guCQ==
        ResponseMetadata
            RequestId
                4f715dcf-9e89-4ad5-b721-5bb1ba6bbafa
        ResponseHeaderMetadata: RequestId: 4f715dcf-9e89-4ad5-b721-5bb1ba6bbafa, ResponseContext : H5F8Si8GvjCkIIlV+vqovD1zOzXDQ+i7/xRZB46IM/XgePQAAliUi6NzK7tCrVsHM/fZFLhjQkM 0Tvk46V5dJCSmZr22uad,2LvooKOfZwPK75jMl3gDmvuK1oCUt3JWf9UvVTFfXSIhrMpIxkcjQp/ekS0I2neiRcoh0X14RWs0 na0j6cY9ZQ==, Timestamp: 2016-03-09T06:55:38.418Z
```

Please provide solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Please provide additional context.  What type of feed are you submitting.  Are you using an SDK?  If so which one?  What language is your code in?  Also, is this the same problem?  [Amazon MWS thread](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2421498)  or [Stack Overflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163536/amazon-mws-api-w-php-alternative-to-getfeedsubmissionresult/18234561#18234561)     The SO thread seems to be your exact same problem and has an answer on it.

Comment: I am submitting "_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_" type of feed. and i am submitting using PHP language.

Comment: Reference the links I provided.  There is an answer to your question in the stack overflow thread.

Answer (score 0):

I get the result in correct format using CURL. I have call API using CURL and i am getting the response in XML format which is actual response.